# C and inline asm bug

Tags: c, linux, pointers, assembly, processor

I'm working on a Linux device driver where I meet an annoying bug that I've reduced to the userland code below.

*The purpose is to read the number of Cores in the Processor through the cpuid instruction*

It appears that a core dump is produced in the third phase **only** and I'm stuck with an explanation ?

Output:

```
Phase 1: FYI Proc=0x1ac1010
Phase 2: CPU count=8
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This code has been written for Linux 4.0.7-2 64 bits, compiled with gcc version 5.1.0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned long CPU_count;
} PROC;

PROC *Proc=NULL;

unsigned long CPU_count;

unsigned long CPU_Count(void)
{
    unsigned long c=0;

    __asm__ volatile
    (
        "movq   $0x4, %%rax     \n\t"
        "xorq   %%rcx, %%rcx    \n\t"
        "cpuid                  \n\t"
        "shr    $26, %%rax      \n\t"
        "and    $0x3f, %%rax    \n\t"
        "inc    %%rax           \n\t"
        "movq   %%rax, %0"
        : "=m" (c)
        :
        : "rax", "memory"
    );
    return(c);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if((Proc=malloc(sizeof(PROC))) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Phase 1: FYI Proc=%p\n", Proc);

        CPU_count=CPU_Count();
        printf("Phase 2: CPU count=%lu\n", CPU_count);

        Proc->CPU_count=CPU_Count();
        printf("Phase 3: CPU count=%lu\n", Proc->CPU_count);

        free(Proc);
        return(0);
    }
    else
        return(-1);
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: It is uncommon to write `unsigned long int`. Just `unsigned long` is enough.

Comment: Are you sure you use the correct type? Better use a fixed-width type from `stdint.h`, e.g. `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned long`.

Comment: Your inline assembly doesn't list any clobbers; likely you're corrupting some processor state.

Comment: I'm cleaning up the code and trying some clobbers but there is still a core dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Carl Norum since you're asm statement doesn't fully describe its effect on the machine state likely what's happening is that you're clobbering a register GCC is using to store some value. Like say the `Proc` pointer.

The solution is to define all the inputs and outputs of your assembly instruction, along with anything else it clobbers. In this case it's also a good idea to do as little as possible in inline assembly, and leave everything else to the compiler. In your example only the `cpuid` instruction needs to be in inline assembly. So try this instead:

```
void
cpuid(unsigned value, unsigned leaf,
      unsigned *eax, unsigned *ebx, unsigned *ecx, unsigned *edx) {
    asm volatile("cpuid"
             : "=a" (*eax), "=b"(*ebx), "=c"(*ecx), "=d"(*edx)
             : "a" (value), "c" (leaf));
}

unsigned long int CPU_Count(void)
{
    unsigned eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    cpuid(4, 0, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);
    return ((eax >> 26) & 0x3F) + 1;
}
```

Note your method of determining the number of CPU cores won't work reliably. On my 4 core CPU your program says I have 8 cores. This is because the field you're extracting gives the maximum APIC id, not the actual number of cores. There's a [thread on Intel's web forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/287414) that addresses this issue.

Comment: Thanks Ross, your answer is the best solution. However I wish one day to master the tricky aspects of inline asm, beside the basic usage.

Comment: BTW for any testers of this Core count algorithm: what you get is indeed the number of logical cores, also called threads in the Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual. Divided by 2, you get off-course the number of physical cores, if Hyperthreading is activated. You can browse Create_Topology() in my code at http://github.com/cyring/xfreq/blob/master/svr/xfreq-intel.c to determine a APIC map, such as an array of [cpu# , apid id , core# , thread#] with which you define the Hyperthreading state.

Comment: @CyrIng My processor has only 4 cores with no hyperthreading support. Your example program in your post here incorrectly says it has 8. You can not use this method to reliably detect the number of cores, physical or virtual.

Comment: Hello Ross. You are totally true, this cpuid leaf is not reliable as a all solution. Although the topic was inline asm, I would suggest to try my project XFreq which implements several algorithms to determine the Cores number: from cpuid to smbios